# Have to grant authorization repeatedly

Tags: google-apps-script

The authorization for some scripts, running on time or form submit triggers, gets lost after some hours.
I granted the authorization with the owner account, several times now, and although nothing gets changed on the triggers or scripts, they keep running into errors due to allegedly missing authorization. After re-authorizing it works for another couple of hours.

Any ideas?

Trigger: time-based -- Error Message: Authorization is required to perform that action.

Trigger: formSubmit -- Error Message: Authorization is required to perform that action.

Comment: Does anyone else use the owner account? They can revoke access...

Comment: Is this inside an Add-on or a normal script? You can try the troubleshooting for that error message: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/troubleshooting#authorization_is_required_to_perform_that_action

Comment: Nope, the access has not been revoked by another user. I'm the only one.
It's a normal script. I already removed all triggers and recreated them, more than one time now :/ Even re-creating them from an incognito window is not providing a solution, unfortunately.